# Unable to read value from location URL using RegEx inside BeanShell Post Processor

Tags: regex, jmeter, beanshell

I am using JMeter to automate performance test cases. After HTTP request, I have used RegEx Post Extractor to read the response header. This response header return location. Location is project-specific URL. I want to read the value of the state variable from this URL. For this, I have used BeanShell PostProcessor. For example,

```
location: "http://www.google.com/state=asdas123123123123&query=asdasdas!@#"
```

I am able to read value of response header as [http://www.google.com/state=asdas123123123123&query=asdasdas!@#"](http://www.google.com/state=asdas123123123123&query=asdasdas!@#%22) using regular expression extractor

Then, I have added BeanShell PostProcesssor to read state and query.

```
import java.util.regex.*;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

try{
//location = "http://www.google.com/state=asdas123123123123&query=asdasdas!@#"
String location = vars.get("location");
String pStr = "/state=(\\S+?)&/"";
Pattern patternN = Pattern.compile(pStr);

Matcher matcher = patternN.matcher(pStr);

    if (matcher.find()) {
        vars.put("variablename_1",matcher.group(0));
    }

    
vars.put("variablename_2",location);
}catch (Exception ex) {
        vars.put("variablename_ex",ex);
    throw ex;
}
```

This code is not working. It seems double slash is creating problems.

Comment: Replace `String pStr = "/state=(\\S+?)&/"";` with `String pStr = "state=([^\\s&]+)";` and then  use `vars.put("variablename_1",matcher.group(1));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. [Since JMeter 3.1 you should be using JDR223 Test Elements and Groovy language](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) for scripting
2. Groovy provides [Find operator](https://groovy-lang.org/operators.html#_find_operator) which looks like `=~`
3. Assuming above 2 points you can refactor your "code" to this one-liner:

   ```
   vars.put('variablename_1', (vars.get('location') =~ /state=(\w+)&/)[0][1])
   ```

Demo:

[image]

More information:

- [Pattern Matching in Strings in Groovy](https://www.baeldung.com/groovy-pattern-matching)
- [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)